# Stop my 2d object from going thru box collider

Tags: android, scripting, controls, game-physics, unity3d-2dtools

So right now I have a box that I can move left/right, and on the sides I have other boxes to stop the player from going into the void. Hard to explain, but basically I have the player in the middle, and then a box on each side to stop the player from running off into the void. Even though I have set everything up with box colliders and ridgidbodies, when I tilt my device all the way to a side the player goes straight thru the boxes, but is I tilt the device slightly the player kinda bounces on the sides and it gets very jerky. How can I make some barrier that will be unpenetrable by any object? Like what do I need to do to make a wall so that nothing will be able to go thru it? Here is the code I am using to control the player, thank you!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Tilt : MonoBehaviour {

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    transform.Translate(Input.acceleration.x * Time.deltaTime * 10, 0, 0);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having this problem because you are using `transform.translate` to move your character. This method will place your character at the assigned position regardless of if there is any collider or not.

As you said you have attached a RigidBody to your character so try using `rigidbody.velocity` to move your character.

For more help have a look at the following [Unity Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/earn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter/moving-the-player).

Comment: rigidbody.velocity doesn't work anymore, it has obsolete API and when I update it there are more errors. Sorry for late response just came out of vacation.

Comment: Did you see the tutorial? It is with the new unity.
And regarding obsolete API: In the new unity you have to get `rigidbody` using `GetComponent()`.

Comment: Thanks! I was really busy so I didn't look at the tutorial for a while, but I finally watched it and it solved my problems! Big thanks, answer awarded! :)

Comment: Here is the tutorial link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixM2W2tPn6c